# Is there any way to use Screen Sharing with audio?

Tags: macos, audio, remote-desktop

So the Mac in my studio has all the power & resources, but I often like just accessing it via screen sharing from a lower specced MacBook.

Screen Sharing (aka vnc) works quite well on a fast network, but there's no audio.

What's strange is if you are using Messages and invite a screen sharing session with another use, there *is* audio. But for reasons beyond my comprehension, Apple have decided to leave that out for straight up screen sharing.

When using Logic, AUNetsend/recieve can work, but it's a but flaky and difficult and frustrating to make it work over WAN (though I have had it working).

Does anyone know if I purchase Apple Remote Desktop perhaps that would enabled audio?

Are there any other methods I've missed?

Comment: What do you consider "straight up screen sharing"? I've never tried piping such as iTunes across it, but when I dial into my folks' Mac half a country away, it automatically engages both mics so we can talk. I connect simply by launching Screen Sharing [the app] then pinging their apple ID to find the Mac. For various reasons I can't test the remote Screen Share Mac right now for sound, nor can I test a local Mac for Microphone communication over RDC - however, Remote Desktop doesn't seem to broadcast its sound to me [I'd never tried it before today].

Comment: Ah - I do have one Mac I can test for open mic on RDC… & no, it doesn't transmit like Screen Sharing does.

Comment: @Tetsujin I mean when you find another Mac on your network in Finder and click Share Screen, vs inviting a screen sharing session via Messages. The latter usually requires 2 people

Comment: No, that doesn't share sound or mic for some reason. I seem to only get mic when I remote to the folks' Mac. Remoting that way to someone right next to me, I get nothing. I can't really test the Messages version, as I'l be pinging people's phones, when they're not already here to explain to;)